# Implementation of AVL Tree

Tags: c++, tree, avl-tree

I am trying to implement an AVL tree. There is a function add node to add nodes to the tree which further calls rebalance function in order to check the balance factor of the nodes being added. add function is working properly but there is being no rearrangement of nodes even when the balance factor goes out of range[-1,1]. The level order traversal returns the same tree every time even after adding the nodes.

```
template<class T>
class avl{
    private:
     Node<T>* root;
     
     //REBALANCE FUNCTION
     Node<T>* rebalance(Node<T>* &node){
      int bal_fact=balance_factor(node);
       if(bal_fact>1){
           if(balance_factor(node->m_left)>0){
             node=ll_rotate(node);
           }else{
             node=lr_rotate(node);
           }
       }
       if(bal_fact<-1){
          if(balance_factor(node->m_right)>0){
             node=rl_rotate(node);
           }else{
             node=rr_rotate(node);
           }
       }
       return node;
     }
     //HEIGHT FUNCTION
     int height(Node<T>* node){
          if(node==nullptr){return 0;}
          int l_height=height(node->m_left);
          int r_height=height(node->m_right);
        if(l_height>=r_height){return l_height+1;}
        else{return r_height+1;}
      }


    //balance_factor
      int balance_factor(Node<T>* node){
        
          int l_height= height(node->m_left);
          int r_height= height(node->m_right);
          int diff= (l_height-(r_height));
          
          return diff;
      }
      
      //LL Rotation(Left Rotation)
    //when the imbalance factor is caused in the right child's right subtree 
      Node<T>* ll_rotate(Node<T>* &grand_parent_node){
          Node<T>* temp = grand_parent_node->m_right;
          grand_parent_node->m_right=temp->m_left;
          temp->m_left=grand_parent_node;
          return temp;
      }
      //RR Rotate 
      //when the imabalance is caused in the left childs left subtree
      Node<T>* rr_rotate(Node<T>* &grand_parent_node){
         Node<T>* temp= grand_parent_node->m_left;
         grand_parent_node->m_left=temp->m_right;
         temp->m_right=grand_parent_node;
         return temp;
      }
      //RL Rotate[Right left Rotation]
      //when the imbalance is in the right child's left subtree
     Node<T>* rl_rotate(Node<T>* &grand_parent_node){
         grand_parent_node->m_right=rr_rotate(grand_parent_node->m_right);
         return ll_rotate(grand_parent_node);
     }
      //Lr Rotate[Left right Rotation]
      //when the imbalance is in the left child's right subtree
     Node<T>* lr_rotate(Node<T>* &grand_parent_node){
         grand_parent_node->m_left=ll_rotate(grand_parent_node->m_left);
         return rr_rotate(grand_parent_node);
     }
    public:
      avl(){
          root=nullptr;
      }
      Node<T>* getroot(){
          return this->root;
      }
     //Height of the AVL tree
      int height(){
          return height(this->root);
      }
      

    //BalanceFactor of a node
      int balance_factor(){
        return balance_factor(this->root);
    }
      
    
 
    
     
     void add_node(T data,Node<T>* &node){
       if(this->root==nullptr){
         Node<T>* new_node= new Node<T>(data);
         this->root=new_node;
         
       }
       else{
         if(data<node->m_data){
           if(node->m_left!=nullptr){
             add_node(data,node->m_left);
            
           }else{
              Node<T>* new_node= new Node<T>(data);
              node->m_left=new_node;
              node=rebalance(node);
           }
         }
         if(data>node->m_data){
           if(node->m_right!=nullptr){
            add_node(data,node->m_right);
           }else{
              Node<T>* new_node= new Node<T>(data);
              node->m_right=new_node;
              node=rebalance(node);
           }
           
         }
       }
     }
     void add_node(T data){
       add_node(data,this->root);
     }
     
 

     void level_order_traversal(){
            if(this->root==nullptr){
                return;
            }
            std::queue<Node<T>* > q;
            q.push(this->root);
            
            while(!q.empty()){
                 Node<T>* current_node= q.front();
                 q.pop();
                 std::cout<<current_node->m_data<<" ";   
                 if(current_node->m_left!=nullptr){
                     q.push(current_node->m_left);
                 }
                 if(current_node->m_right!=nullptr){
                     q.push(current_node->m_right);
                 }
            }
        }
};
              return height(this->root);
          }
          int height(Node<T>* node){
              if(node==nullptr){return 0;}
              int l_height=height(node->m_left);
              int r_height=height(node->m_right);
            if(l_height>=r_height){return l_height+1;}
            else{return r_height+1;}
          }
    
        //BalanceFactor of a node
          int balance_factor(){
            return balance_factor(this->root);
        }
          int balance_factor(Node<T>* node){
            
              int l_height= height(node->m_left);
              int r_height= height(node->m_right);
              int diff= (l_height-(r_height));
              
              return diff;
          }
     
        //LL Rotation(Left Rotation)
        //when the imbalance factor is caused in the right child's right subtree 
          Node<T>* ll_rotate(Node<T>* grand_parent_node){
              Node<T>* temp = grand_parent_node->m_right;
              grand_parent_node->m_right=temp->m_left;
              temp->m_left=grand_parent_node;
              return temp;
          }
          //RR Rotate 
          //when the imabalance is caused in the left childs left subtree
          Node<T>* rr_rotate(Node<T>* grand_parent_node){
             Node<T>* temp= grand_parent_node->m_left;
             grand_parent_node->m_left=temp->m_right;
             temp->m_right=grand_parent_node;
             return temp;
          }
          //RL Rotate[Right left Rotation]
          //when the imbalance is in the right child's left subtree
         Node<T>* rl_rotate(Node<T>* grand_parent_node){
             grand_parent_node->m_right=rr_rotate(grand_parent_node->m_right);
             return ll_rotate(grand_parent_node);
         }
          //Lr Rotate[Left right Rotation]
          //when the imbalance is in the left child's right subtree
         Node<T>* lr_rotate(Node<T>* grand_parent_node){
             grand_parent_node->m_left=ll_rotate(grand_parent_node->m_left);
             return rr_rotate(grand_parent_node);
         }
         
         void add_node(T data,Node<T>* node){
           if(this->root==nullptr){
             Node<T>* new_node= new Node<T>(data);
             this->root=new_node;
             
           }
           else{
             if(data<node->m_data){
               if(node->m_left!=nullptr){
                 add_node(data,node->m_left);
                
               }else{
                  Node<T>* new_node= new Node<T>(data);
                  node->m_left=new_node;
                  node=rebalance(node);
               }
             }
             if(data>node->m_data){
               if(node->m_right!=nullptr){
                add_node(data,node->m_right);
               }else{
                  Node<T>* new_node= new Node<T>(data);
                  node->m_right=new_node;
                  node=rebalance(node);
               }
               
             }
           }
         }
         void add_node(T data){
           add_node(data,this->root);
         }
         
         Node<T>* rebalance(Node<T>* node){
           int bal_fact=balance_factor(node);
           if(bal_fact>1){
               if(balance_factor(node->m_left)>0){
                 node=ll_rotate(node);
               }else{
                 node=lr_rotate(node);
               }
           }
           if(bal_fact<-1){
              if(balance_factor(node->m_right)>0){
                 node=rl_rotate(node);
               }else{
                 node=rr_rotate(node);
               }
           }
           return node;
         }
    
         void level_order_traversal(){
                if(this->root==nullptr){
                    return;
                }
                std::queue<Node<T>* > q;
                q.push(this->root);
                
                while(!q.empty()){
                     Node<T>* current_node= q.front();
                     q.pop();
                     std::cout<<current_node->m_data<<" ";   
                     if(current_node->m_left!=nullptr){
                         q.push(current_node->m_left);
                     }
                     if(current_node->m_right!=nullptr){
                         q.push(current_node->m_right);
                     }
                }
            }
    };
```

Comment: It's a good time to debug your program.

Comment: @Evg Done! all values seem right to me !

Comment: @Tushar Then you are not looking properly. You know it's right at the beginning, you know it's wrong at the end. Somewhere in the middle is where it goes wrong, that's what you should be using the debugger to find out.

Comment: @Tushar Honestly you will get far far more out of this situation if you learn how to use a debugger effectively. than if someone does your debugging for you and tells you what is wrong with your code.

Comment: Okay i am doing it once again!